# mysql select query to select from single table with multiple WHERE clauses

Tags: mysql

i am new to database querying so apologies for this rudimentary query question. thank you in advance.

```
table called "neuron"  
columns in "neuron" called "neuron_id", "neuron_name" + others (not relevant here)
```

neuron_id is unique identifier for each neuron_name;
say there are 5 entries, thus
neuron_id = 1,2,3,4,5 and corresponding
neuron_name = a,b,c,d,e

i would like to generate a list that contains neuron_id for select neuron_name. the following query does not work for me.

```
select neuron_id, neuron_name  
from neuron  
where neuron_name = "a" or "c" or "e"
```

i expect the following

```
1,a  
3,c  
5,e
```

but the above query only spits out

```
1,a
```

Comment: `WHERE neuron_name IN ('a', 'c', 'e')`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select neuron_id, neuron_name  
from neuron  
where neuron_name = "a" or neuron_name = "c" or neuron_name = "e"
```

**Edit:**

The solution from ypercube is more semantically correct.

```
select neuron_id, neuron_name  
from neuron  
where neuron_name IN ('a', 'c', 'e')
```